# Add days and loop over dates for a number of weeks

Tags: python

I did this,

```
>>> d1 = datetime.date(2018, 7, 26)
>>> d2 = datetime.date(2018, 10, 14)
>>> dif = d2 - d1
>>> start_mon =(d1 - datetime.timedelta(days=d1.weekday()))
>>> num_of_weeks = math.ceil((d2 - start_mon).days / 7.0)
>>> num_of_weeks
12
>>>xp = [d1 + datetime.timedelta(i) for i in range( math.ceil((D2 - start_mon).days / 7.0))]
>>> [datetime.date(2018, 7, 26), datetime.date(2018, 7, 27), datetime.date(2018, 7, 28), datetime.date(2018, 7, 29), datetime.date(2018, 7, 30), datetime.date(2018, 7, 31), datetime.date(2018, 8, 1), datetime.date(2018, 8, 2), datetime.date(2018, 8, 3), datetime.date(2018, 8, 4), datetime.date(2018, 8, 5), datetime.date(2018, 8, 6)]
```

I want python to give me the weekdays between 12 weeks. So since the start date is 2018-07-26, the next date should be 2018-08-02, next should also be 2018-07-09 till it ends at 2018-10-11 . and if if after count it's 12 weeks.

e.g

```
2018-07-26
2018-08-02
2018-08-09
2018-08-16
2018-08-23 
2018-08-30 
2018-09-06 
2018-09-13 
2018-09-20 
2018-09-27 
2018-10-04 
2018-10-11
```

what am I missing?

Comment: So you want only the weekdays out of those 12 dates?

Comment: yeah. just keep adding 7 days to start date and stop when it gets to 12. Like this 2018-07-26
2018-08-02
2018-08-09
2018-08-16
2018-08-23 
2018-08-30 
2018-09-06 
2018-09-13 
2018-09-20 
2018-09-27 
2018-10-04 
2018-10-11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop, adding 7 days with each pass.

```
xp = [d1]
while (d2 - d1).days > 7:
    d1 += datetime.timedelta(7)
    xp.append(d1)
```

In-place addition works in this case because `datetime` objects are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Here another try :

```
import datetime

d1 = datetime.date(2018, 7, 26)
d2 = datetime.date(2018, 10, 14)

days = d1
while days < d2:
    print(days)
    days += datetime.timedelta(7)
```

Comment: awesome thanks! Can't upvote. But your solution works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also used this function.

```
>>> def next_days(st_date, end_date):
    if st_date <= end_date:
        print (st_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
        next_date = st_date + timedelta(days=7)
        next_days(next_date, end_date)


>>> st_date = datetime.date(2018, 7, 26)
>>> end_date = datetime.date(2018, 10, 14)
>>> next_days(st_date, end_date)
```

)